# rails 3.0.11 javascript_include_tag automatically includes an extra JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

**Rails 3.0.11, Ruby 1.9.3**

When I use a javascript_include_tag("js/datepicker") in my view file
it includes 2 files.

```
<script src="/js/datepicker.js?1336410184" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/widgets/tooltip.js?1332959153" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*Note the second one I didn't specified, still its getting included.*

I have following folders and files:

```
/public/javascripts
/public/javascripts/widgets
/public/javascripts/widgets/tooltip.js

/public/js
/public/js/datepicker.js
```

My application uses Prototype and jQuery.The datepicker.js is actually the Protoplasm Datepicker control.

**/config/application.rb**

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery jquery_ujs jquery.prettyPhoto)
```

Can anybody please make me understand what is the cause behind **/javascripts/widgets/tooltip.js** getting automatically included?

Thanks,

Jignesh

Comment: Do you have a layout that includes additional javascript files? Generally the layout will include application.js, which in turn will include a tree (directory) where other javascript files are placed.

Comment: @Salil - yes there is a layout in the header element of which following is included: `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`.But **/javascripts/widgets/tooltip.js** is not included anywhere and :defaults includes **jquery jquery_ujs jquery.prettyPhoto**.Am not getting any idea on from where it is getting included.

Comment: Can you search through your plugins to see whether any plugin is setting config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults]. And see that none of them are in after_initialize hook, which can override  your application.rb code initialization of the javascript defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.

Following is the plugin included in my application:

rails-widgets-jquery (http://github.com/paolodona/rails-widgets/wikis)

A file named **core.rb** of this plugin at **rails-widgets-jquery/lib/widgets/core.rb**

redefines the javascript_include_tag which is causing the behavior mentioned in my question.

Source Code below:

```
module ActionView
 module Helpers
   module AssetTagHelper

  # We redefine javascript_include_tag in order to auto-magically include
  # the widgets javascripts. If you hame more than one javascript_include_tag
  # call, the widgets javascripts gets included only once.
  def javascript_include_tag_with_widgets(*sources)
    unless @__widgets_has_already_included_its_js
      options = sources.last.is_a?(Hash) ? sources.pop : {} # remove options
      sources << 'widgets/tooltip'
      sources << options # add previously removed option
      @__widgets_has_already_included_its_js = true
    end 
    javascript_include_tag_without_widgets(*sources)
  end
  alias_method_chain :javascript_include_tag, :widgets 
  end
 end
end
```

Thanks @Salil for your responses.Those helped me getting to above answer.

Thanks,
Jignesh